# how to run a function in ram that it was copy from SD Card

Tags: compiler-construction, stm32, boot, keil

I have a STM32 CortexM4 microcontroller that has a limited flash memory size.
There are many classes in my keil project that they'r never run together.
So i have decided to run these classes distinctly after compile and converting them to a bin file in SD card memory. Whenever i need a class,
i want to copy the bin file from SD Card to internal RAM (in the correct fixed address for example 0x20010000). **How can i implement this procedure correctly in the KEIL compiler?**
of course i don't want to do any change to my hardware. and i have many other function and classes in my project that they will called by the other classes that i want to copy to RAM, i means that useing Boot loader does not help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

i found it.
i used overlays.
like this:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08020000 0x000E0000; load region size_region
{
    ER_IROM1 0x08020000 0x000E0000; load address = execution address
    {
        *.o (RESET, +First)
        *(InRoot$$Sections)
        .ANY (+RO)
    }
    RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00018000    ; RW data
    {
        .ANY (+RW +ZI)
    }
}

LR_IROM2 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load region size_region
{
    my_Rom2 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load address = execution address
    {
        myAlgorithm1.o (+RO)
    }
    my_Ram2 0x2001E000 OVERLAY 0x00002000    ; RW data
    {
        myAlgorithm1.o (+RW +ZI)
    }
}

LR_IROM3 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load region size_region
{
    my_Rom3 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load address = execution address
    {
        myAlgorithm2.o (+RO)
    }
    my_Ram3 0x2001E000 OVERLAY 0x00002000    ; RW data
    {
        myAlgorithm2.o (+RW +ZI)
    }
}

LR_IROM4 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load region size_region
{
    my_Rom4 0x20018000 OVERLAY 0x00006000; load address = execution address
    {
        myAlgorithm3.o (+RO)
    }
    my_Ram4 0x2001E000 OVERLAY 0x00002000    ; RW data
    {
        myAlgorithm3.o (+RW +ZI)
    }
}
```